# Get string of either side of a desired letter

Tags: python, string

How to get the string of either side of letter 
EG
email@gmail.com

If the desired letter was "." it would print "l" and "c" from "gmail" and "com"

I do not think that using `[]` to separate the letter would work as I think the algorithm is much more complicated

Comment: *using [] to separate the letter* - what do you mean?

Comment: like str[5:-5] as you do not know the location of the letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution using `re` module:

```
s = 'email@gmail.com'
l = '.'

import re

print( re.findall(r'(.)?{}(.)?'.format(re.escape(l)), s))
```

Prints:

```
[('l', 'c')]
```

---

EDIT: To get only first match you can use `re.search`:

```
s = 'email@gmail.com'
l = 'l'

import re

print( re.search(r'(.)?{}(.)?'.format(re.escape(l)), s).groups() )
```

Prints:

```
('i', '@')
```

Comment: This is great, because I can use the square brackets to only select the last "." search

Answer (score 1):

Use `index()`.

```py
def getNeighbors(string, desired):
  index = mystring.index(desired)
  return mystring[index-1], mystring[index+1]

mystring = 'email@gmail.com'
desired = '.'
print(getNeighbors(mystring, desired))  # >>> ('l', 'c')
```

A couple notes:

This will return the characters around the *first* instance of `'.'`. It also does not perform bounds checking. Finally, it does not check that character actually exists in the string.

Comment: Awesome, just added in some try and except statements to print if you are missing the letters around the "."